# How to update ListView dynamically on each iteration of a sorting process in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an `ArrayList` of 9 integer values. I want to sort this `ArrayList` based on ascending order of values. After each iteration, I want to display the list in a `ListView`. After next iteration, the `ListView` should update with the result of new iteration.
I used the below code for sorting. But i dont know how to refresh the `ListView` on each iteration.

```
            Integer[] numbers = new Integer[] {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};    
            ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
            numberList.addAll( Arrays.asList(numbers) );  

            List list = numberList;

            //Method for sorting list
            doSort(numberList);

            // Create ArrayAdapter using the number list.  
           listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.listdata, numberList);

            // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
            mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );     

      }

      public static void swap(List<Integer> sort, int i, int j) {
            int tmp = sort.get(i);
            sort.set(i, sort.get(j));
            sort.set(j, tmp);

      }

      public static void doSort(List<Integer> sort) {
            int min;
            for (int i = 0; i < sort.size(); ++i) {
                //find minimum in the rest of array
                min = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < sort.size(); ++j) {
                    if (sort.get(j) < sort.get(min)) {
                        min = j;
                    }
                }

                //do swap
                swap(sort, i, min);

            }

       }
```

Comment: you mean each forloop iteration in the doSort?

Comment: Yes.Exactly like that

Comment: but you already sort it before you add it to the ListView.

Comment: yeah.thats where i have doubt.i just did that for checking whether sorting is done correctly.i want it to be done in the other way.displaying each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Sort your list like this

```
public void sort(ArrayList<Integer> sort){
Collections.sort(sort, new Comparator<Integer >() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return (o1<o2 ? -1 : (o1==o2 ? 0 : 1));
    }
 });
}
```

Then just make this call to your list adapter

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

The sort method will do sorting in Ascending order to change it to Descending 
just change `o1<o2`  to `o1>o2`

Comment: the sorting method work for sure i have used it.
and you call notifyDatasetChanged() whenever you sort the list

Answer (score 0):

Call the sorting method on a background thread. Then at each iteration notify the adapter of the listview in the UI/Main Thread.

```
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  // <----- this line before sorting.
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSort(numberList);
            }
        }).start();
```

Upadte the list view:

```
    swap(sort, i, min);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
        }
    });
```